# _render function not working in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have integrated jQuery UI's autocomplete with Rails using the link below:

http://www.lugolabs.com/articles/20-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-ruby-on-rails

For some reason I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined
    at app.PopularSchools._initAutocomplete (inner_layout.self-7e73ad8….js?body=1:231)
    at app.PopularSchools (inner_layout.self-7e73ad8….js?body=1:220)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (inner_layout.self-7e73ad8….js?body=1:213)
    at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:3233)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:3363)
    at Function.ready (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:3583)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:3618)
```

My application.js file:

```
//= require inner_layout/jQuery-2.1.4.min
//= require rails-jquery-tokeninput
//= require inner_layout/bootstrap.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require inner_layout/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min
//= require inner_layout/app.min
//= require inner_layout/owl.carousel.min
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require jquery-ui
//= require cocoon
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require ../common_js/custom
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
//= require tinymce
//= require common_js/jquery.raty.js
//= require_self
```

The complete code is:

```
$(function () {
    new app.PopularSchools;
});

var app = window.app = {};

app.PopularSchools = function () {
    this._input = $('#search-txt');
    this._initAutocomplete();
};

app.PopularSchools.prototype = {
    _initAutocomplete: function () {
        this._input
            .autocomplete({
                source: 'popular_schools/get_all_schools',
                appendTo: '#search-results',
                select: $.proxy(this._select, this)
            })
            .autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = $.proxy(this._render, this);
    },
    _render: function (ul, item) {
        var markup = [
            '<span class="name">' + item.name + '</span>',
        ];
        return $('<li>')
            .append(markup.join(''))
            .appendTo(ul);
    },
    _select: function (e, ui) {
        $("#id").val(ui.item.id);
        $("#type").val(ui.item.type);
        this._input.val(ui.item.name);
        return false;
    }
};
```

**Edit: 
Per comments added `<head></head>` contents:**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon-fc4de0140d07a7fb9ab4f50fa2e0f48d215231c90c716a0109942cb07ec4459e.jpg">
  <title>Site Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/common_css/bootstrap.self-8eed0a962b1f6cd0dee143c17da4398c45c23dda6b4a036e98cd700010aaa12e.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/common_css/bootstrap-flex.self-b3cbfd57f1adb9aa0f7d0bf99f76ef8eda3f57482eb4dfe5b0c7799f863bf4a5.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui.self-80de8350e5025ebca2c2899295a636ec9bd4608f09787334c5c92c102fff5939.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/token-input-facebook.self-5074a1bc7f07d8d2125d9c63eae7450c5ad544c9fdf8f29a016eb1ad704a738b.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/daterangepicker.self-3ac07b1b1cacfb4e8ec02be3bf11cbb672db20240ac86ea331391451e5fd2cdb.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/prettify.self-f2a5364acbaf236a6fd79eca52d2b47063b66aebb2381bb9688cfa40ae1246bf.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/theme.self-830c3407ba1359ea36eee978235be14de5b78dacfa658a31226fe4f2b0faa7e7.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/autocomplete.self-f0b810a4a7bb8c90994675d7c5bfe636d615a5785cf81cae3340aa5e6adc55ca.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/common_css/font-awesome.min.self-053e8e59e362ea6dfaaa1d47542e9ac73bb508aaa8a108e78a5af17c78b28f79.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/common_css/material-design-iconic-font.min.self-0721df3f25a30e97b682c1ae0404435c893068dd3b51ee6947a762965d419569.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/inner_layout/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.self-222a444a523a37f06879d29860c9757240e74d1770b219a6a9ad00676e9d3445.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/inner_layout/weevur.self-717c50da898a613886688634a4131f7a63b4b747feda890032a779e756263ead.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/inner_layout/weevur-theme.self-20b31bcd58caa9be715480411040758dd09ae37734ed64c06be62797e707a061.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/style.self-0acb00764e0eb2fad99b783ee67311c94aef7d46add583515a4d09cc8ee828e4.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/inner_layout/inner_layout.self-b57a4eaaabb432402eb122602acd085692f2d94eb274d1eabbfb06b2ce3b671e.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/inner_layout/_color-variable.self-a7d19b357431705284de31486cf7e915f9513f6e01633a475743b7252197b23f.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/inner_layout/owl.carousel.min.self-6570efd06433eaf06c957ee48fb13c1d97f89b239526aa5e4f1b8f9ca10ccbe1.css?body=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/inner_layout/owl.theme.self-3e80d06e340350c29e5ed031a85f9529dbea92d25d960ae4c7cfcd31ea1b722b.css?body=1">
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var pusher = new Pusher('34c0cdbc218bac1d4dac', {
        encrypted: true
      });

      var channel = pusher.subscribe('channel-' +70);

      channel.bind('notification_event', function (data) {
        $("#notification").fadeIn("slow").html(data.message + "<span class='dismiss'><a title='dismiss this notification'>X</a></span>");
        $("#notification_drop").prepend("<li class='notices'><a href=" + data.url + ">" + data.message + "</a></li>");
        $("span#notification_count").text(parseInt($('span#notification_count').text())+1);
        $("span.badge").text(parseInt($('span.badge').text())+1);
        $(".dismiss").click(function () {
          $("#notification").fadeOut("slow");
        });
      });
    </script>

  <script src="/assets/inner_layout/jQuery-2.1.4.min.self-92bfaaece1eee1e40fd3b55441ee536e7f6a03242aa5fe10e2597a27103c9dae.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.tokeninput.self-b727cdd4b322bd427f485dd21b9248b710f4ce186350c53b3c35ef515264ed2d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails-jquery-tokeninput.self-2b46449b4d53a7134ff76a0a5abaf2a66b3f223ce373498d131468ab6944c634.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/inner_layout/bootstrap.min.self-504d59678f10d79a661b6cecdce5b8c1d5bfd98e860614584c0a40399552d61f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/inner_layout/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.self-682cbac60ea68d85ee1d08249eb4c1a73b83e659f5ad8dde9406d06715d88b0b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/inner_layout/app.min.self-7175e52be5d1868e9c02087f9030953eaadcb4c11b35feb69f48afa29e6b5ce5.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/inner_layout/owl.carousel.min.self-1a656d9fbdd97437fabb09a673bcfbd8dcd61704a72fe5ce95bd52799a9afab7.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.iframe-transport.self-b58640d2146e10a028d4aec4f1c6e624305f8b5edd02cbb5ca77f7fb56b4d976.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.remotipart.self-1660679e325ee534ce863e680eb6ad0bc9739d262594dc1337a2171e5c19c939.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/version.self-c8e3d1203da26ea7efdf83c1eabb3f0ba55cb68e463f5ccf0d77bd15ce6a8e61.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/data.self-2067c82e6fe39a9cba5623206a5dc28d5c60d26b95cd100855b78cacf72865b8.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/disable-selection.self-5675f71f2fbbc6857ea700ba843af748b50dbc0150cc87932a7d05ec016bb659.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/focusable.self-426e99e67d1f1bd4cb444fd878ee63a6de1f5d1d61451e43022c86214b9eec64.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/form.self-711978b53107be2d9ef1b7369beb151b229cefa8c1405a056d3c34262d5b477e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/ie.self-163eb039dcb1e0c3471b7d91386eabb8753da6906e84824c019f9ff56bdb83a6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/keycode.self-ad63cd20acf49dd333bbbc537454d7d475bd610eb5b88de0dca009f0c3d314b1.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/escape-selector.self-43e4d61501e4ffb1ecba387affbae1eb3e1c863ab0b0e71897851cddd246e50e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/labels.self-c0448a3cb597a9a9429be814ab0e9ed2a14d85604555b4cff897adf3f0415f38.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/jquery-1-7.self-22c197e38fc01a29431530c4c5c7263e26d2b611994b1f9c5c8c900a97b4bc44.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/plugin.self-d8f576c8e073ca51f095505f47bd09d306b875404cd90afcbb6338287cfb0247.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/safe-active-element.self-a1f1a1a7dae3269ce03f6fffb2dcc9b4a7490f5d546c65d54417bec3be24b668.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/safe-blur.self-2cc24c46132d51c7724f6371154241b0a81c9bae5d5681d8f62b01ce46236726.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/scroll-parent.self-38e26a71a450a29fb63425e8f589a7046862f927eb0a1dbf6a6c44da05196d2e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tabbable.self-f3f62ceed772d3a325cebd6a03221f8a8cb02c6150f4feba738c6525a2953690.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/unique-id.self-66e85ac85cd0b6b8b1bb89369fc65f608f716869dc0930862a8d421a57a9580a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/core.self-886760af898381620a8980841c646ae70e894b5292c3138e6dfd75b6904deffb.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect.self-776455da1682afff3a4974146aa96ca840597b879ed3797af0604063527443c6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/form-reset-mixin.self-3a447942586b5719fdd7f1d1a3ac0da9e757a0eb8f4a7cb145f6deb820d2dc54.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/position.self-1b49c8c521e67a4a88bfdad6b4d944d33686d25009a0e40a1e170acdd7b6962a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self-fca20bcec06d192f97cffa6e734e24360e227237b8ae7d7e7e60754df7d5444f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-blind.self-2f8923f5c3073717dad35ac1f9bd4dbc13d2f9c8128f7dbea9819921338271f4.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-bounce.self-ca3686abc7c667b5380422af36b618923c2fc8e901b3eb2ff627f1cdef60486a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-clip.self-9e606afd1b0d1679f42b1ce5c2ad29f242ed98a9b1a473a9ef8a8bf10df2afe4.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-drop.self-481600061a28b5621b1d78187468e63f057665ce6af6401db851f9b79e345965.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-explode.self-b5f68a634df4bc19111474eb15bcd99597dc19c721b33647fbb04f2bb6d52ca3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-fade.self-60febf4d2a1f6f013852a42da59c74d840f205715162a2b11e734fd4dd73a519.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-fold.self-78adc6cc7f2d8dac25e8c82164ae61cc3160bb5280ed3d24dd96a576e37a6e46.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-highlight.self-842a0db414abed8fbccb48908bd933b32c93c6b9d725160c85dc2bde708fa753.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-size.self-2094878ac7ba38dcd4539cd4595fa4d6ed7182be8bb6f03785684a5e470a293d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-scale.self-88872e591cdbf30b3d09946e82e96e25bcd99b03857ead844a503301e6de71f3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-puff.self-be0ba8a98762bf10054deb4e8bdf92c44de0d570714624d16c396f1ffe3a82d6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-pulsate.self-bf83d1979be265f242fceb95cc3cfeca5467e4aab9cdea27ebb6f2e17bdaae2e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-shake.self-867270f4e72f7895d38b10fdf9a6ba20f22bee88ac4d79654a9227c14141e1ca.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-slide.self-b59b0b36df7b3e5e4f4190ab51e5c212744d2b34d5ed14c96bfe9c8a3096c00b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-transfer.self-5ab6d30ecb0b73e2b9a528f6d66c0732ba43a93a5326d88dae547f0c7c759e79.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/accordion.self-267aabfe487e53fce0399a77f9030a87b9d8a409eb30c4c85c5637da9ac35429.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/menu.self-0730fe713007bd93e6db569352a20ed92448299505ff6f525bc0dc6dd488254e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete.self-6a89d7a43741ec810ef95de143a7c0297e2e4368ebecff64493ebb7a9ac3a524.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/controlgroup.self-0b7409f97114a33de116bd5429e9df199cbdea3f276d8bd725c4c2c60f244711.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/checkboxradio.self-60f68cb16012ef210c931076ada2d65d54a8c74a2dc71ce383af758460f8b686.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/button.self-659b51f6fb5303f90ed8cf551509063770a50168a15795ba834b08f8bf2e0ce0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker.self-2af0dec09da99d687c31fc224e940687a4eb3694e7b38b0871bba475cad86120.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/mouse.self-f0790a202dcf54fab051e71b042335d5346f9cceb0f645223c1dab93f349a04b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/draggable.self-42c3eda0b49f105628cea7580fe38c7ed77467cee384bb2c4e095a2bd0a172e6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/resizable.self-1a46c2f5b876918e02bf979080e56f57846590cd880721bca5058e84f7f60bae.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/dialog.self-2bd687f9580c0be4213c50b4bb1211c28ceedb045eba954e63d40bfbb4d1affd.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/droppable.self-4e3be0d7524dd1852e3b37ae00cd0c351c6178bcad39b17315cca941ddd44148.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/progressbar.self-3bf965ce4e8ade2f07336ae5ffce7fe58897333238561761ffcb16f31af673fc.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/selectable.self-a364da09c555890f5bb64704711594a88e94988edb285735bda59431a749226e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/selectmenu.self-43e0fc6b5fba037933a7d89a5b2a7127aa9c7494cc605c2dcd3146265e2d3d35.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/slider.self-f166e8b345d6a2376ab8f43b05ab7629016706df83f2d96113cf5d8905c3d028.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/sortable.self-6e5e1f07a29b5a89ec1d359363d2800904e3ae548a38ab2f8eded36746d1adbe.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/spinner.self-2769386b6b06e175a13ccdcd6d2d0cd40c45cec19607bcb818cee0704c165557.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/tabs.self-b7f60535e992224ca66c3f11dc943eba9ef42a9605241e27b9dba24c7efb287e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/tooltip.self-50ae9488af573c99a78b60209bce5c7a4affc4e175fef523942acb163dd8deb8.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.self-d4c1ae19d9b853ec1c8c83784fa979bbe4075a84932a080bbd7d7706240410e1.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/cocoon.self-6874ad698cefd21cc1119b773550f61b5c1a60396460f015222af59293affe80.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/autocomplete-rails.self-5d8d93a5f6e19ab6e682b9dd9999592b61ff3c3d69ea242a830a8556158001fa.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/moment.self-0da3eb4ebf8fb8c3113d89afb90e5b7a87760d21b5b39a405a51fe05c8e40fd8.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-datetimepicker.self-8b304d8493b536f56ff5f3a0cba6238693fb968d72400f3f794b7196c9f5a47f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/common_js/custom.self-a29ebf4c7dcdfb350f3a879097b570cc1b032e4a8fb8115a235243ad937ea469.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/tinymce/preinit.self-84328a53e798df12f891eb49871773fd9f925439c8630e9e22423a82ef9e6f89.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/tinymce/tinymce.self-53684479d33d944177c9037e73854f0a1eb0fa64c5657dedcf4f1aa04b959145.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/tinymce.self-75a11da44c802486bc6f65640aa48a730f0f684c5c07a42ba3cd1735eb3fb070.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/common_js/jquery.raty.self-628421be04f36f7a8fa8b9b884c6d7824d6f8bdeba4f172b131f15aa63f713e8.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/inner_layout/inner_layout.self-d4064f8473922f8fa4cce0e23e1195e4f5d2cc1a4e55bdd3c981fbd7a10b27ea.js?body=1"></script>
  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="TT0D01RZkj4Ox7IFyrBvPSXboqLHXdnJfRjrq5UNpnalRkODkR2icapP7DbWGNSiITNrGWo7h5uBxJW+xpmRVg==">
<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.10.2/css/TB.min.css"></head>
```

Comment: I've setup a basic test to see if I can replicate the issue, and I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pw5cvghr/ I get a similar error trying to init autocomplete. Investigating.

Comment: Found my typo in the selector, and have a now working example that does not replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pw5cvghr/3/

Comment: I got this to run without proxy: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pw5cvghr/4/ and with: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pw5cvghr/5/ Still unable to replicate the issue. I wonder if something is causing the  jQuery UI to not load properly in your setup. Do you see any errors in your console? Can you update your post with the `head` details of the resulting page?

Comment: @Twisty massive thanks for your replies. The only error I see is something like: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined`. Sorry, `head` details means? So I will add them as well. :-)

Comment: The content in your `<head>` tag of the resulting html

Comment: I have just added the `<head>` content.

Comment: One thing I notice is that there are 2 jQuery libraries loading: `jQuery-2.1.4.min` and `jquery-ui/jquery-1-7` and am wondering if this is creating a conflict. The error you're encountering suggests that `autocomplete` does not exist or have an instance when you call `_renderItem` attribute. Can you check your javascript console and see if there are any other errors before hand that indicate a SRC is not loading?

Comment: I think this might be creating conflict that 2 jqueries are loading. :) 
The reason is that my console has only on error related to `_renderItem`. Apart from that my console has no other single errors.

Comment: Not sure what you'll want to do then. Could remove anything you don't need.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for the concern. Means a lot to me. 
No, unfortunately I didn't figure it out. My project is so big and I couldn't afford to debug the `js` step by step so what I did is to insert the code in the end of required pages where it was needed. `abc.html.erb` and inside it I insert code of `js` within script tags and with this the error has got removed but you know thats not the good rails way but sometimes we are forced to take such actions to avoid uncertain obstacles.